# Laravel Subdomain Route URL

Tags: php, laravel

*Example route/web.php file*

```
// base_url example.com
Route::domain('app.example.com')->group(function(){
  Route::get('/','ExampleController@method')->name('home1');
});
Route::get('/','ExampleController@method')->name('home2');
```

How to make;

- route('home1') return -> http://example.com
- route('home2') return -> http://app.example.com

always.

When going from home1 to home2, the subdomain changes, but when changing from home2 to home1 it stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap routes with main domain

```
Route::domain('app.example.com')->as('domain1.')->group(function(){
  Route::get('/','ExampleController@method')->name('home');
});
Route::domain('example.com')->as('domain2.')->group(function(){
  Route::get('/','ExampleController@method')->name('home');
});
Route::get('/','ExampleController@method')->name('home');

route('domain1.home');
route('domain2.home');
```